# Can a SQL index distinguish between `Doe, John` (1 space) and `Doe, John` (2 spaces)?

Tags: sql

In a `people` database, there's a table with `author_names`, that's referred to from a couple of other databases. Author_names must be unique.

Don't ask me how, but someone managed to create different entries in `author_names`, for nearly identical terms. For example, there's `Doe, John` (one space) pointed to by some records x, y, z, and a different entry for `Doe,  John` (two spaces), pointed to by different records p, q, r.

We want to clean up. Now, we can use equivalents. That is, if we had author `Doe, Johannes` who is the same person als `Doe, John`, we can make them equivalents, and everything will be OK. (I.e. if you search for author Doe, John, you also get hits on Doe, Johannes and vice versa.)

The problem is that SQL sees `Doe, John` and `Doe,  John` as identical terms. And therefor refuses to make them equivalent, because that violates the unique requirement.

What would be the way to work around this (other than manual cleaning, record by record)?

(I checked dba.stackexchange, but there's much more on SQL here.)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing first and last name in the same column to begin with. But yes `'a b'` is considered to be different from `'a       b'`

Comment: In what situations do you find "SQL sees `Doe, John and Doe,  John` as identical terms"? Can you not update the records that currently point to `Doe,  John` (two spaces) to instead point to `Doe, John` (one space)? and then delete `Doe,  John` (two spaces)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you point to what setting in MSSQL Server turns the distinction on or off?

Comment: There is no setting for this. This is how it works out of the box https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c68b37dfbc64204a90912c05cbe08b4

Comment: @user9601310 Yes, we could, but that's a lot of manual work. I'm looking for a smarter way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Aha, thank you! This means that not SQL, but the application on top of it makes the distinction.

Comment: By "update" I meant using SQL to update the foreign key references, not by doing manual work!!  i.e. `update tablea set authorname = 'Doe, John' where authorname = 'Doe,  John'`  with tablea being the table that contains your p, q, r records. BTW, a_horse_with_no_name's example fiddle demonstrates that SQL does make the distinction between one and two spaces. The query returns only the row that matches with one space.

Comment: @user9601310 Thanks, that's helpful! There are some 400 names to correct, referred to by multiple tables. So this becomes a nice SQL exercise. I might be back with a different question when I get stuck.